# Database how to model 1:1 relationship

Tags: sql, database, linq, linq-to-sql, database-design

(VS2008, SqlCE 3.5)

I try to model a **1:1** relationship. So I put the foreign key in the parent table, holding the PK of the child table. Then I set the foreign key to UNIQUE.  Still when I create my entity classes (With SqlMetal), the child class has a reference to an **EntitySet** of the parent, not just a single entity. This seems like a **m:1** relation?  So what I need to do to make it 1:1 ?

---

**EDIT1:**

I'm confused.. Trying to make a set, like this:

```
StrategySet(ID, EntryStrategyID{Unique}, ExitStrategyID{Unique})   
EntryStrategy(ID) 
ExitStrategy(ID)
```

Is this m:1 isn't it?   Though it looks like FK's are in the parent, or wouldn't we name StrategySet the parent?     And how would I now change this too 1:1 ?

Comment: In my experience, 1:1 relations are generally a sign of something that hasn't been modelled correctly (and need to be merged)

Comment: Actually, I discovered when I wrote my question that I DO actually want it to be m:1 anyway. But I still would like to understand how 1:1 is modeled, now that I started to wonder how it's done.

Comment: @smirkingman: "In my experience, 1:1 relations are generally a sign of something that hasn't been modelled correctly" -- If you meant to say, "1:1 relationships" then your experience may be unusual e.g. husband/wife relationship is usually 1:1 and very commonly encountered.

Comment: Why don't you explain a bit what are you trying to model? Do `EntryStrategy` and `ExitStrategy` have common columns -- and how many? Are there specific columns for each one?

Comment: There are no common columns. They each have about 20 separate columns. And StrategySet is just a table to pair an Entry strategy with an Exit Strategy. So if I make EntryA/B/C and ExitA/B/C, I could have StrategySet:  EntryA & ExitA  and  EntryA and ExitB.. etc. Just so I don't need to copy all entry parameters when I just want to change the Exit parameters.

Comment: @onedaywhen, "husband and wife" like most other relations should ideally be modelled with an association class and a date range in between...

Comment: @onedaywhen You would be ill advised to model husband-wife as 1:1. For example, my father-in-law had 5 different wives. Furthermore, in countries where polygamy is acceptable, your model would fail. Amusingly, the OP seems to have come around to my position >;-)

Comment: @Randy @smirkingman: most database comprise 'current state' tables. 'Valid time state' tables are vastly more complex in SQL and will continue to be so until (if?) we get the SQL3 extensions. But when you mention extreme cases such as polygamy I _know_ you are being facetious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me understand the situation you are describing.

You have set of fields which make up a "Strategy". A subset of the fields are conceptually the "EntryStrategy" and a non-intersecting subset of the fields are the "ExitStrategy".

In your case a given set of values making up an "EntryStrategy" can be joined with one and only one set of values making up an "ExitStrategy". This is what you mean when you say there is a 1:1 correspondence.

As smirkingman said earlier, in classic relational database modeling, all of these fields belong in a single table because no subset of the fields appear in more than one record.

If you could have multiple ExitStrategies for a single EntryStrategy then you would have two tables with the EntryStrategy being the parent and the ExitStrategies being the children and the ExitStrategy records would have a Foreign Key pointing to the EntryStrategy parent record.

If you could have multiple EntryStrategies for a single ExitStrategy then you would have two tables with the ExitStrategy being the parent and the EntryStrategies being the children and the EntryStrategy records would have a Foreign Key pointing to the ExitStrategy parent record.

If you could have multiple EntryStrategies associated with multiple ExitStrategies then you would have a many-to-many relationship which requires a third table to maintain the correspondences.

The principles of classic database modeling would put all your fields in one table.

As St Woland wrote, you can enforce the 1:1 relationship by having two tables where the foreign key in the child table is a Unique index. But two tables are normally used for 1-to-many relationships.

As Damir wrote, you can enforce the 1:1 relationship by having three tables where the third table has a foreign key to each of the other two tables and both foreign key fields are marked as Unique indices. However, normally you only use three tables in this fashion when you have a many-to-many relationship.

I think you are expecting way too much from the automated data modeling tools to expect them to construct entities that represent your very unconventional approach.

The answer to your main question is simple. How do I represent a 1:1 relationship? You put them in the same record in a single table!

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. Been researching database for 5 days now, starting to understand a bit more.

Comment: One more comment. I appreciate your desire to retrieve only a subset of the fields rather than the entire record. You can use views or stored procedures to define and retrieve a subset of your record without messing up your 1:1 relationship by breaking it into two tables.

Comment: I see, I haven't learned about views and stored procedures yet. Actually the reason why I want 1:1 over multiple tables is that a single table would have ~100 columns, which logically can be nicely separated, so it feels more manageable for the purpose of oversight when working with the database model.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `parent` is table which is referenced by FK from `child`. So you can't say that your parent table *references* the child: it's not correct.

Secondly, 1:1 relations can be made through:

- Primary Keys in both tables
- Primary Key in parent and Unique Foreign Key in child

So in your case, the architecture is correct. I suppose you should check the structure again, and look through [this article](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=72762).

Comment: So is it my wording that is incorrect? Does it not describe correctly what I posted in the EDIT ?

Comment: EntryStrategy and ExitStrategy are `parent`, StrategySet is `child`. Unique constraints are OK, but you will get m:1, if you use compound UNIQUE constraint (on 2 fields at the same time, and that's what you want in current situation). If you use 2 UNIQUE constraints, then it would be 1:1

Comment: Ok, I see I'm confused with parent/child naming...  But what other fields can I set as unique as you suggest? The ID's of EntryStrategy and ExitStrategy?  I thought they were inherently unique, since they are PKs?   Or you mean I need to introduce some additional fields (to get 1:1)?

Comment: Actually re-reading your last comment I see that I don't understand what you mean.   It seems you separate between A) Compound Unique constraint, on 2 fields, and B) 2 unique constraints..    I'm sorry I don't see what is the difference of these meanings..?

Comment: That is correct, PK's are unique already. Do you have a compound or separate UNIQUE constraint on EntryStrategyID and ExitStrategyID? To make it 1:1, they have to be separate.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about this distinction compound/separate.  How is this set practically?   I just edit the StrategySet table, selecting Unique = Yes from the dropdown at each of those two fields.

Answer (score 1):

If all columns in `EntryStrategy` and `ExitStrategy` are the same, then all you need is simply this (add all other columns too).

[image]

If `EntryStrategy` and `ExitStrategy` have some different columns, then use this. Keep all common columns in the `Strategy` table. `EntryStrategy` and `ExitStrategy` have only columns specific to each one.

[image]

Here is also a generic example of `1:1` due to vertical partitioning of a table.

**Before**:

[image]

**After**:

[image]